# How do I enable Basic Authentication for IIS 8 in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8

I have a website that needs to use Basic Authentication. I want to host it on a Windows Server 2012 box. But in IIS in the Authentication page for the web site, Basic Authentication is not available.

How do I enable Basic Authentication for IIS 8 in Windows Server 2012?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open an elevated command-prompt or PowerShell:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-BasicAuthentication
```

Now you will have the Basic Authentication option in the Authentication page in IIS Manager.

This works in Server Core and is much quicker than using the GUI.

Comment: In addition to this answer, it may be worth to comment that you will probably need to perform an `iisreset` after doing this.

Answer (score 8):

In server manager, in Web Server (IIS)/Security, add Basic Authentication which then should show up in IIS web site authentication settings.

Comment: Where is the security option?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an older topic, but I had the same question as **epotter** regarding where to find the option. I discovered that it's actually part of the IIS role in Server Manager's 'Add Roles and Features', Under 'Web Server', 'Web Server', 'Security'. You should find Basic Authentication as a check box.

Dirk

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what the most up voted answer was also referencing.

Comment: This is likely another path to enable the same thing as in the accepted answer via GUI mechanism.